# .in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: networking, dns, virtual-machine, nameservers, reverse-dns

I have been struggling with this for about 3 days now. I will continue to work on it as I wait for anyone to help but I'm having the following problem. I will use examples in this post to mask the domains and IPs somewhat. This is not to make more work for you I just don't want it easily cached in search results on google etc. Thank you in advance for any help

I have installed **WHM on a Cloudlinux system** hosted on a **VM using VMWare**. The domain(In this case lets call it **domain.co.za**) was used as the hostname of the system and if you go to that domain it actually loads. That domain name is pointing to Cloudflare which in turn points back **A** records to the **WHM** server as the nameservers i would like to use. This system is currently using PowerDNS as well

Now what I also have encountered is that the **ns1.domain.co.za** is working fine(This is also the machines hostname) but the **ns2.domain.co.za** is not

If I try to set nameservers for any other domains it does not allow me to change them and they are giving the following errors

> Authoritative Nameserver failure for domain

This I am assuming is because of the following error when I use intoDNS to check what the problem is(this is not for **domain.co.za** this is for a domain I own called **orginc.co.za** which only the ns1.domain.co.za is accepted and not ns2.domain.co.za)

> The following nameservers are listed at your nameservers as nameservers for your domain, but are not listed at the parent nameservers

When I use a dig command I get the following results for ns2(Please note actual IPs changed)

```
Host 20.20.20.164.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
[root@ns1 ~]# dig ns2.domain.co.za

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.3 <<>> ns2.domain.co.za
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 61082
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns2.domain.co.za.                IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 164.20.20.20#53(164.20.20.20)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb 13 12:11:12 SAST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

I have been reading around and it seems like the general consensus is that it is a reverse DNS issue but I'm not sure how to proceed. I get answers like the following that I found on a cPanel forum

> This functionality only works if your data center has delegated permission to your server to control the entry

But at the end of the day, we own the physical hardware that we put in at the data center.

I do not know how to proceed at the moment but will keep trying in the meantime

Comment: "This is not to make more work" ... yet it does create more work and less relevant answers for you, besides the fact that your question has nothing to do with programming hence is offtopic here. "the general consensus is that it is a reverse DNS issue" I don't know who this general is, but it is most certainly not the issue. Since you don't want to give the names, use online troubleshooting tools like Zonemaster or DNSViz for your DNS needs. Or ask your hosting/DNS provider to explain the problem to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok everyone so the sequence of events went as follows.

1. List item There was an **A** record mismatch on WHM itself as **ns2.iclixhosting.co.za** was not set in the **iclixhosting.co.za** zones
2. Reverse DNS had to then propagate
3. We then had a firewall issue that needed a bypass for port 53 on that IP

In other words for future people reading this answer make sure of the above-mentioned items if you have problems similar to this

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming domain.co.za is a `dummy` domain name and not the actual one.

From what I’ve read so far, it seems that you may have some troubles with domain NS.

first thing to check is who’s configured as NS for `domain.co.zak

```
$ dig NS domain.co.za
```

Then make sure whatever NS entries are returned, those servers must have the zone entries for the domain. What I am assuming is the case is that you have `ns1.domain.co.za` as well as `ns2.domain.co.za` but for one reason or another, only one of these is aware of your entries.

Typically you’d host your zone on `ns1.domain.co.zak and then you authorise` ns2.domain.co.za` to fetch your zone entries (known as AXFR) so this way both name servers are in sync and have all the zone entries. This might be where the problem is if ns2 is unable to fetch the zone. This is a long shot in the dark here, but you can try this:

```
ns2$ dig @ns1.domain.co.za AXFR domain.co.za
```

NS2 should be able to obtain zone entries from NS1.

Again, all the above is just a wild guess ;-)

Comment: Hey @Danail, Thank you for the response. So I tried this and what I got back from the dig NS was the cloudflare servers. On there I do have an A record set up for ns1 and ns2. I do not have multiple machines for DNS(What i mean by this is I don't have a DNS server set up for ns1 or for ns2) i am trying to accomplish this in one machine. I will take a look as to how to authorize ns2 to get the zone records from ns2. I did try this command on the machine but it responded with transfer failed with 1 server found

Comment: What is what you have setup for NS entries for your domain? Is it ns1 & ns2? typically you need to setup at least two NS per domain.

Comment: Yes it is ns1 and ns2. Im not sure why ns2 is not picking up on reverse DNS either. gives that error: .in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: this is not really related to your domain name. the reverse (PTR) records are function of your IP address space and not on your domain name.. for that you’d need to have access to your ip address space’s in.addr-arpa zone

Comment: Hey Danail, Been working over the weekend and I seem to have sorted out the reverse DNS issues. Waiting for propagation then I will let you know if it is sorted